# Update icon badge daily at midnight

Tags: ios, auto-update

I am making an app which shows the number of days since two people are in a relationship. I would like to show the number of days on the app icon badge. I know how to do this once the user leaves the app, however I want to update the icon badge everyday even if the app isn't opened or running in the background so the user knows the number of days without having to even open the app. "BeenTogether" is a similar app and is doing the same so I am sure it is possible somehow. Any thoughts on how could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure that variations of this have been asked about a zillion times, but the answer is still no. There are ways you can approximate it, but all have downsides.

- Silent push notification. Of course this means you need to know their time zone and they need to have a network connection.
- Background fetch. This operates "periodically" so you couldn't update the badge at *exactly* midnight but it would often be pretty close.

Comment: Stephen, I have heard about the push notification approach however that seems rather complicated for such a simple task. Background fetch though seems like an actual solution, does it work even if the app is closed in the background? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it will launch the app (in the background) if it's not running. However it's not 100% reliable.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve same thing with help of Local Notification. I assume that you're having date when they started date. So, you can update badge count everyday with Local Notification.

Comment: Could you show me some code on how would I do that?

Comment: You can schedule notification at every 24 hours with current date. iOS allows to schedule max 64 notifications. So, you need to write logic accordingly.

Comment: Nice idea. The problem is you have to be running to create/edit notifications. Would you create a handful of notifications in advance and hope the user launches again to re-generate them?

Comment: Oh yeah, I have heard about this approach but I am trying to avoid that if it's possibld because if the app is not opened for 64 days it will stop updating

Comment: You can repeat the notification, but how would you increment the badge number?

Comment: I guess you would need to write the logic for that and schedule the 64 notifications in advance

Comment: You could combine background refresh with this approach to reset the scheduled notifications each day

Comment: Wouldn't it be fine just to go with background refresh? It's ok if the badge does not update exactly at midnight

Comment: That's your call - it is your app

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure everyone understood my question right, because it turns out to be possible to increment the icon badge by one everyday at midnight, without having to schedule 64 notifications. The solution is rather simple:

```
//Set a random date (only the time matters because it is repeated everyday), but make sure that the time is at midnight!!
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[dateComponents setYear:2015];
[dateComponents setMonth:1];
[dateComponents setDay:1];
[dateComponents setHour:0];
[dateComponents setMinute:0];

//Create an NSDate from the date components
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc]  initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSDate *configuredDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComponents];

//Schedule a local notification, set the repeatInterval to daily
UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate = configuredDate;
localNotification.alertBody = nil;
localNotification.alertAction = nil;
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitDay;

//Add one to the icon badge number
localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```